# VisualforceArrayList.name

Tags: visualforce

this is the vfp snippet

```
<apex:pageblockSection title="Results">
            <apex:outputText value="{!results.name}"></apex:outputText>
        </apex:pageblockSection>
```

this is the controller

```
public class empRegController {

   String searchText;
   List<Contact> results;

   public String getSearchText() {
      return searchText;
   }

   public void setSearchText(String s) {
      searchText = s;
   }

   public List<Contact> getResults() {
      return results;
   }

   public PageReference doSearch() {
       results =  [Select name, Employee_No__c, Email, Phone FROM Contact WHERE Employee_No__c =:searchText ];

      return null;
   }

}
```

Comment: u hv access individual contact from the list and then use the fields of the contact.

Comment: i used a controller because im using search box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method in returning list means it contains more than 1 contact records

```
 public List<Contact> getResults() {
      return results;
   }
```

that's why use apex:repeat to iterate over list (like we do for loop in apex)

```
<apex:repeat value="{!results}" var="res">
   <apex:outputText value="{!res.name}"></apex:outputText>
</apex:repeat>
```

This way you can display all the contact Name